# Kicked from Windows 2003 Server and need to reboot

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, windows-7, connection

The situation is:

Several Win7 users are connecting to a database housed on a Win2k3 Enterprise server and every so often they will get kicked out of the server entirely. They lose all of the information they were working on.  The network is stable because they can use other servers, and browse the web.

The only way to reconnect to the server is to restart the computer and reconnect to the specific server.

Comment: Are they all losing the connection at the same time?

Comment: No, everyone seems to be experiencing the occurrence at random intervals and times.

Comment: What database are they connecting to ?
And when you say they are kicked out of the server and lose their work, is this the work they have been doing in the database, or something else on the server, like file shares ?
Can they ping the server, access shares, etc. when they are disconnected ?

Answer (score 0):

Track memory usage.  I found some poorly written MS SQL backend apps eating all memory till the server crashed.  I "fixed" it by doing a scheduled reboot overnight since the vendor had no interest in fixing it.

Comment: I will check that out AX.  To my knowledge their should be no MSSQL instances running on that specific machine but I will focus on the memory usage when the issue rears its head again.